# Stop cell from being dragged out of UITableView bounds

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitableview, uikit

I have a `UIVIew` on which I loaded a `UITableView` as subview. The tableView is exactly the height of all it's rows(4 of them) heights sumised, about half the height of the main view.

The problem is that when I drag a row to move it I am able to drag beyond the bounds of the table and this cuts my cell's view (I am only able to see the part that is still in the table's bounds).
Is there a property I can change to stop the cell from being dragable out of the table's bounds?

Comment: You need to provide some code to us to be able to help you what you're doing wrong,normally you can't be able to drag a row beyond your table's bound.

Comment: You don't actualy move the cell over the bounds , it's more like under them in the sence that when u move them past the bounds you only see the part that is in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this like below..

```
[yourtableview setBounces:NO];
```

let me know it is working or not!!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Unfortunately I still doesn't work...i can still move the cell past the bounds and at that poin i only see the part of the cell that is in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If the `UITableView` is exactly the height of the 4 rows . Then you **Do Not Need** the Scrolling functionality of the `UITableView` and you can simply stop the scrolling by :-

```
TableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Hope this is what you wanted . Please tell otherwise.

Comment: I'm not scrolling...I'm moving the row to a new position